# JPG File Chooser (Android) doesn't work

Tags: android, file

I've got the JPG File Chooser from [android-coding.blogspot](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/05/jpg-file-chooser.html)

Java - 1.7; Android - 2.2; Eclipse.

```
package com.androidcustomdialog;

 import java.io.File;

public class AndroidCustomDialogActivity extends Activity {

 Button buttonOpenDialog;
 Button buttonUp;
 TextView textFolder;
 ImageView image;

 String KEY_TEXTPSS = "TEXTPSS";
 static final int CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID = 0;

 ListView dialog_ListView;

 File root;
 File curFolder;

 private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        buttonOpenDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opendialog);
        buttonOpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
            }});

        root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        curFolder = root;
    }

 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

  Dialog dialog = null;

  switch(id) {
     case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
      dialog = new Dialog(AndroidCustomDialogActivity.this);
      dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
      dialog.setTitle("Select JPG");

      dialog.setCancelable(true);
      dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

      textFolder = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.folder);

      buttonUp = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.up);
      buttonUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View v) {
              ListDir(curFolder.getParentFile());
          }});

      //Prepare ListView in dialog
      dialog_ListView = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);
      dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
              File selected = new File(fileList.get(position));
              if(selected.isDirectory()){
                  ListDir(selected); 
              }else {
                  Toast.makeText(AndroidCustomDialogActivity.this,
                          selected.toString() + " selected",
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  dismissDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);

                  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selected.getAbsolutePath());
                  image.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }}});
         break;
     }
  return dialog;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle bundle) 
 {
  super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog, bundle);
  switch(id) {
     case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
      ListDir(curFolder);
         break;
     } 
 }

 void ListDir(File f)
 {
  if(f.equals(root)){
   buttonUp.setEnabled(false);
  }else{                            //115 134 54
   buttonUp.setEnabled(true);
  }

  curFolder = f;
  textFolder.setText(f.getPath());

  File[] files = f.listFiles();
  fileList.clear();
  for (File file : files)
  {  
       if(file.isDirectory()){
        fileList.add(file.getPath());
       }else{
        Uri selectedUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        String fileExtension
         = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(selectedUri.toString());
        if(fileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")){
         fileList.add(file.getPath());
        }
       }
  }

  ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList
   = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
  dialog_ListView.setAdapter(directoryList);
 }
```

There are no errors before start, but after pressing "Load JPG" it is "stopped unexpectedly". The logs are:

```
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): java.lang.NullPointerException 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at com.androidcustomdialog.AndroidCustomDialogActivity.ListDir(AndroidCustomDialogActivity.java:129) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at com.androidcustomdialog.AndroidCustomDialogActivity.onPrepareDialog(AndroidCustomDialogActivity.java:111) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2555) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2514) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at com.androidcustomdialog.AndroidCustomDialogActivity$1.onClick(AndroidCustomDialogActivity.java:54) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
07-24 07:43:10.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5634): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is at line 54 of code from above?

Comment: showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);

Comment: you have a nullpointer on that line so there is some error in code for custom_dialog

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly printed in the log - you've got a `NullPointerException` occurring at line 129.

The lines don't match up the source you've printed however, so it's hard to identify the error exactly. My guess would be that either `f` in `ListDir` is null, or `f.listFiles()` is returning `null` because `curFile` is not a valid directory.

Comment: Right - sorry for that (I removed libraries).
Errors are in:
- for (File file : files) (129)
- ListDir(curFolder); (111)
- showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID); (54)

Comment: In that case `f.listFiles()` is returning `null` - and you can't iterater over `null`! this means that the file referred to by `f` is not a directory (see [File.listFiles() docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles())). So there's your error.

Comment: Have you got the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: No. I've changed the directory and now it works, but if folder doesn't have permission (r-- as far as I know), the app stops.
Where in manifest should I place it (after/before <application>)?

Comment: Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` before `</application>` - see [AndroidManifest.xml](http://code.google.com/p/battery-indicator/source/browse/AndroidManifest.xml?spec=svn68c990638b10fa71bd92c0559542ad861e68815f&r=68c990638b10fa71bd92c0559542ad861e68815f) for an example.

Comment: I think if the folder is empty you might also get a null back, so you should check for null and display "empty folder" if so.